# How to read attribute of child element with DOMParser in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom, domparser

I have this xml

```
<zone name="main">
        <card number="4" price="0" name="Urza's Tower"/>
        <card number="4" price="0" name="Urza's Power Plant"/>
        <card number="4" price="0" name="Urza's Mine"/>
        <card number="4" price="0" name="Urza's Avenger"/>
        <card number="1" price="0" name="Urza's Miter"/>
        <card number="4" price="0" name="Howling Mine"/>
```

And I'd like to read the name attributes. I try this but it doesn't work:

```
 var cards = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("zone")[0].childNodes;
      for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        console.log(cards[i].getAttribute("name"));
      }
```

When I view `cards[i]` in the debugger it shows all the attributes. I just can't seem to access them...

Thanks!

Comment: try changing the `var cards = ...` to `var cards = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("card");`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in the question is using [`.childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) so it’s not getting just the `card` element nodes but also the text nodes between the `card` elements.

To get just the `card` element nodes, use [`.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) instead, like this:

```js
 var cards = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("zone")[0].children;
      for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        console.log(cards[i].getAttribute("name"));
      }
```